# SSRS - Custom parameter layout was removed from the report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I installed a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2015 on a new computer as well as the SSDT December preview. Report server is SQL Server 2008 R2. I can view and build my reports successfully, no problems there, but for about half of the reports I get the following warning message:

```
Custom parameter layout was removed from the report. /
SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services and earlier do not support custom parameter layout.
```

The message appears every time I clean/rebuild, so something isn't changing permanently like VS claims. I don't even know what a custom parameter layout is, so I'm pretty sure I don't need to worry about this. How can I either disable the warning message or fix the problem it's complaining about?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The correct thing to do is to use Visual Studio 2008 for deploying reports to SQL Server 2008 R2.

If you use a newer version of Visual Studio, it will generate reports with xmla elements that SQL Server 2008 does not recognize.

Comment: VS 2016/7 should be able to create/deploy to earlier versions.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: Confirming Jordan's comment. Disabling the XAML Designer no longer stops the ReportParametersLayout section from being generated.

Either ignore the message or manually remove the ReportParametersLayout section from each report.

**Prior workaround: (No longer works as of Update 3)**
If I understand correctly, it appears the warning is caused by the XAML Designer in VS2015 sending data which is only compatible with SQL 2016 or later.

I'm guessing VS devs could resolve the issue if they add some logic to stop XAML Designer output when we select any "TargetServerVersions" earlier than 2016.

Until then, you could:
1.) Continue to ignore the warnings
2.) or you could disable XAML Designer so you will no longer get the warning messages. (Tools > Options > XAML Designer > Uncheck "Enable XAML Designer" then restart VS2015)

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable the custom parameter layout by commenting out or removing the `<ReportParametersLayout>...</ReportParametersLayout>` tags and all inside it in code view of the report.

Comment: But then the parameters disappear from the designer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not change anything (XAML Designer settings), deploy the report anyway. It will work on the server. Make sure your parameters are all set properly, and when you run this report in preview mode in Visual Studio/MSDT there are no errors (warnings are ok) in "error list" pane, even if the report isn't running. If you are using Visual Studio/MSDT 2015 or later and deploying it on servers earlier then 2014, this message will appear, and report may not run in Visual Studio/MSDT (2015 or later).

Answer (score 1):

Change the TargetServerVersion in the properties of the Project file to match your actual SQL server version.

Comment: I've done that, it doesn't help.  Still get the warnings.

Comment: Changing our TargerServerVersion to 2016 or later (which we are) was the only thing that helped us. Deleting <ReportParametersLayout... > deletes the parameters from the Designer. The only thing that caught me was you have to make sure to change the TargetServerVersion on all configurations.